# How to write a non-today date in latex with localization formatting?

Tags: formatting, datetime

I've tried googling around and all I have found is a lot of example on how to format `\today`. But that isn't what I want. Instead, I want a way to format historical dates based on the localization given to babel.

Say, 'June 3rd 1994' in USenglish and UKenglish?

Comment: Maybe `datetime` is an option: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime

Comment: So, you want to be able to write something like `\catInBox` and get back `August 12, 1887` (Schrodinger's birthday)?

Comment: I want to give something like {June, 3, 1994} and get back
June 3rd 1994, 3rd June 1994, 6 Juin 1994,3 de junio 1994, etc. Depending on the language/localization of the document.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's how to do it using [`datetime`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime) :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish,UKenglish,french,spanish,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}

\newcommand{\mydate}{\formatdate{3}{6}{1994}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{french}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{italian}
\mydate

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]

**Edit:**

The `datetime` package has now been replaced with [`datetime2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2). This only requires a few minor changes to the above example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish,UKenglish,french,spanish,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\newcommand{\mydate}{\DTMdisplaydate{1994}{6}{3}{-1}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{french}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\mydate

\selectlanguage{italian}
\mydate

\end{document}
```

The result looks like:

[image: Image of result]

I've used the expandable version `\DTMdisplaydate`. This can be used in PDF bookmarks. There's a robust non-expandable version `\DTMdate` that has a slightly different syntax:

```
\newcommand{\mydate}{\DTMdate{1994-6-3}}
```

The result is the same.

Answer (score 6):

We can use the [isodate](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/isodate) package too, whith the same results as in Nicola's answere:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,UKenglish,french,spanish,italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{isodate}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\printdate{1994-6-3}

\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\printdate{1994-6-3}

\selectlanguage{french}
\printdate{1994-6-3}

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\printdate{1994-6-3}

\selectlanguage{italian}
\printdate{1994-6-3}
\end{document}
```

The \printdate command allows many input formats.

[image]